# Which SSIS transformation can perform 'NOT IN' constraint used in SQL query?

Tags: ssis

I have two OLEDB Data Sources that have similar columns:

```
TMP_CRUZTRANS
-------------
CUENTA_CTE numeric (20,0)

TMP_CTACTE_S_USD
----------------
CON_OPE numeric(20,0)
```

I need to substract all the similar values between this two tables and keep the rows which are different. Is there a transformation/task within SSIS that can perform **`NOT IN`** constraint normally used in SQL query?

Currently, I am performing this operation using `Execute SQL Task` on `Control Flow`.

[image]

The top Data Flow creates the first table `TMP_CRUZTRANS` (Merge join between other 2 tables... But I guess that's not important for my question) that i need to keep the different values with the second table.

In the `Execute SQL Task`, I have the following statement:

```
INSERT  INTO [dbo].[TMP_CYA] 
SELECT RUT_CLIE, CUENTA_CTE, MONTO_TRANSAC 
FROM [dbo].[TMP_CRUZTRANS]
WHERE CUENTA_CTE NOT IN (SELECT CON_OPE FROM TMP_CTACTE_S_USD)
```

Finally, with the new table `TMP_CYA` I can continue with my work.

The problem with this approach is that the `TMP_CRUZTRANS` got like 5 millions of rows, so it's VERY slow inserting all this data into a table using Execute SQL Task. It takes about like 5 hours to perform this operation. That's why I need to do this inside the Data Flow task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **`Lookup transformation`** available within Data Flow task to achieve your requirement.

Here is a sample that illustrates what you are trying to achieve.

Create a package with data flow task. Inside the data flow task, use OLE DB Source to read data from your source table `TMP_CRUZTRANS`. Use Lookup transformation to validate the existence of the values against the table `dbo.TMP_CTACTE_S_USD` between given columns. Then redirect the non-matching output to OLE DB Destination to insert rows into table `dbo.TMP_CYA`

Here is how data flow task would look like in place of the Execute SQL Task that you are currently using.

[image: Data flow task]

Configure the `Lookup transformation` as shown below:

On the General tab page, select `Redirect rows to no match output` from `Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries` because you are interested only in non matching rows.

[image: Lookup transformation General]

On the Connection tab page, select the appropriate OLE DB Connection manager and select the table dbo.TMP_CTACTE_S_USD. That is the table against which you would like to validate the data.

[image: Lookup transformation Connection]

On the Columns tab page, drag the column CUENTA_CTE and drop it on CON_OPE to establish the mapping between source and lookup tables. Click OK.

[image: Lookup transformation Columns]

When you connect the *Lookup transformation* with *OLE DB Destination*, **Input Output Selection** dialog will appear. Please make sure to select **`Lookup No Match Output`**.

Here is the sample before executing the package.

[image: Before execution]

You can see that only 2 rows non matching rows have been transferred to OLE DB destination.

[image: Execution]

You can notice that the destination table now contains the two non matching rows after package execution.

[image: After execution]

Hope that helps.